# Angularjs http request is not working?

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a problem like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Wedima</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/intro.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-5 panel" style="background-color:#BED3F4" ng-app="myModule">
{{10+30}}
    <div ng-controller="introCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in results">
            <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.vision }}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have crate a web page using angularJs.I want to get data from database using php.I have create Php and Intermediate javascript files as follows.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
app.controller("introCtrl", function($scope) {
   //$scope.m="Tharindu"
   $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: '../php/getData.php'
   }).then(function chica(response) {
        $scope.results = response.data;
   });


});
```

This is my javascript file which contain the controller.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sel = mysqli_query($con,"select * from vendor");
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
 $data[] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"vision"=>$row['vision'],"description"=>$row['description']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is my php file which retrieving data from database. But this is not working .Without this HTTP request if i define a variable I can access in the view.But when I used it with this nothing was happened.I tried lot of examples have provided  in the stack overflow.But I was Unable to get it done.How can I get solve this problem?

Comment: $http is not injected in controller `app.controller("introCtrl", function($scope)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
app.controller("introCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
   //$scope.m="Tharindu"
   $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: '../php/getData.php'
   }).then(function chica(response) {
        $scope.results = response.data;
   });


});
```

Comment: @RahulSharma why can you tell me?Now it is working but nothing is retriewed from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var request = $http.get('../php/getData.php');
request.then(function (response) { 
       $scope.results = reponse.data;
});
```

Note: remember to inject $http module in your controller

Answer (score 0):

try below code, it depended to country dropdown and, on change country dropdown state dropdown events called.
feel free to ask any query.

```
<?php
//load_country.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "amit_db");
$output = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY country_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>  
<?php
//load_state.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "amit_db");
$output = array();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_id='" . $data->country_id . "' ORDER BY state_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>  
<?php
//load_city.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "amit_db");
$output = array();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE state_id='" . $data->state_id . "' ORDER BY city_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>  
//index.php
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Dynamic Dropdown list using AngularJS in PHP</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <br /><br />  
        <div class="container" style="width:600px;">  
            <h3 align="center">Dynamic Dropdown list using AngularJS in PHP</h3>  
            <br />  
            <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="loadCountry()">  


                <select name="country[]"  ng-options="y.country_name for  y in countries" ng-model="country" class="form-control" ng-change="loadState()">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>  
                </select> 



                <br />  
                <select name="state[]"  ng-options=" state.state_name for state in states" ng-model="state" class="form-control" ng-change="loadCity()">  <option value="">Select state</option>
                </select>  

                <br>
                <select name="city" ng-model="city" ng-options="city.city_name for city in cities" class="form-control"><option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>  
</html>  
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("usercontroller", function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log($scope);
        $scope.loadCountry = function () {
            console.log('called loadCountry');
            $http.get("load_country.php")
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.countries = data;
                    })
        }
        $scope.loadState = function () {

            console.log('called loadState');

            if ($scope.country)
            {
                console.log($scope.country.country_id);
                $http.post("load_state.php", {'country_id': $scope.country.country_id})
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.states = data;
                        });
            }

        }

        $scope.loadCity = function () {
            var state = $scope.state.state_id;
            console.log("state :" + state);
            $http.post("load_city.php", {'state_id': state})
                    .success(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.cities = data;
                    });
        }
    });
</script>
```